# iOS App is crashing once I tap on the app in my iOS9 iPhone6 simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My app is crashing if I tap on the app,I got a xyz.ipa file from which i extracted xyz.app file and installed the app on my simulator using `open -a "Simulator.app"` and `xcrun simctl install booted /Users/path/xyz.app`, app was successfully installed on my sim but once I tap on the installed app it is crashing

Comment: does it crash if you install it normally via Xcode on the same simulator?

Comment: I do not have code, all i have is ipa file

Comment: do we lose app bundles when we extract from ipa

Comment: app is opening and closing in simulator,is there anything I am missing or should ask my developer to fix it for me ?

Comment: well, show the issue to your developer, maybe he/she can help

Comment: you have to debug the application using code,only we will get to know about the problem of crashing